# Python prints None

Tags: python

Here is the code:

```
class className:
    def createName(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def displayName(self):
        return self.name

    def saying(self):
        print "Hello %s " % self.name

first = className()
second = className()

first.createName('Bob')
second.createName('Tony')


print first.displayName()
print second.displayName()

print 20*"_"

print first.saying()
print second.saying()
```

The question is the following - when I call the second method (saying) why is the result:

```
Hello Bob
None
Hello Tony
None
```

Why the `None`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All `functions/methods` that don't specify a `return` value will `return None` by default so you are just seeing the return value when you print the method.

Either `return "Hello %s " % self.name` instead of printing or just call the method without using `print`.

On a side note you don't need and should not use getters in python, to access `self.name` just `print first.name` etc..

Answer (score 0):

Return the value, don't print it:

```
def saying(self):
    return "Hello %s " % self.name
```